# hook_custom_theme() works except if a user submits a user form with mismatched passwords. Then they get served the admin theme

Tags: 7, theming, users

Title basically. My `hook_custom_theme()` has been working for ages and I only just realised the admin theme is being served for an error when saving a user form ie. mismatched passwords.

A snippet from the top of my function:

```
function custom_theme_change_custom_theme() {
    global $top_bar_color;
    $top_bar_color = '#2b3643';
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'example.com') !== false) {
        switch (returnRoleForTheme()) {
            case 'old': $th = 'theme_1'; $top_bar_color = '#2b3643'; break;
            case 'young': $th = 'theme_2'; $top_bar_color = '#6dad19'; break;
            case 'kid': $th = 'theme_3'; $top_bar_color = '#6dad19'; break;
        }
    }
    return $th;
}
```

Any ideas on how to force the theme like for every other part of the website? Why would this page in particular revert to Adminimal?

Answer (score 0):

hook_custom_theme()'s [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7.x) says :

> The return value of this hook will be used on all pages except those
>   which have a valid per-page or per-section theme set via a theme
>   callback function in hook_menu(); the themes on those pages can only
>   be overridden using hook_menu_alter().

so i guess that what you need here is having your custom rules ina  helper function that you call both in hook_custom_theme() and the theme callback of the error page from hook_menu_alter()